# Ordem alfabética no While?

Tags: php

Tenho uma listagem de professores em um site, e ela está sendo imprimida por ordem cronológica, e eu queria colocar por ordem alfabética.

Segue código:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="team-list sort-destination appear-animation animated fadeInUp appear-animation-visible" data-appear-animation="fadeInUp" data-appear-animation-delay="50" data-sort-id="team">
        <? while ($p = $prof->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){?>
            <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 isotope-item <?=str_replace(' ', '-', tirarAcentos($p['materia']));?>">
                <div class="team-item thumbnail">
                    <p class="thumb-info team">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://editoraopirus.com.br/uploads/<?=$p['unidade'];?>/professores/<?=$p['url_foto'];?>">
                        <span class="thumb-info-title">
                            <span class="thumb-info-inner"><?=$p['nome'];?></span>
                            <span class="thumb-info-type"><?=$p['materia'];?></span>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        <? }?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Não podes mudar a query à base de dados para ordenar por ordem alfabética? A base de dados é muito mais rápida nessa ordenação que o PHP ou JavaScript

Comment: Você tem que mexer na Query que traz esses professores. Basta dar um `ORDER BY nome ASC`

Comment: Obrigado, Vou testar!!

Answer (score 3):

Caso nao possa mudar na sua query SQL (recomendado)

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` ORDER BY `nome` ASC
```

[8.2.1.13 ORDER BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

--

Pode usar o [sort()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sort.php)

```
$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
sort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}

?>
```

Sera impresso:

```
fruits[0] = apple
fruits[1] = banana
fruits[2] = lemon
fruits[3] = orange
```